# Transaction disappears when using windsor + nhibernate

Tags: asp.net, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor 3.0 for dependency injection in a demo ASP.NET app. One of my controllers takes an ICustomerService instance, which in turn takes an ISession instance, all via constructor. The ISession is registered with Windsor using a factory method and PerWebRequest life style.

```
_container.Register(Component.For<ISessionFactory>().Instance(DbHelper.BuildSessionFactory()).LifestyleSingleton());
_container.Register(Component.For<ISession>().LifestylePerWebRequest().UsingFactoryMethod(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()));
```

In the global.asax file, I have an Application_EndRequest handler that attempts to commit the transaction:

```
protected void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (!IsStaticResourceRequest())
    {
        var app = (HttpApplication)sender;
        var factory = _container.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
        var session = ManagedWebSessionContext.Unbind(Context, factory);

        if (session != null && 
            session.Transaction != null && 
            session.Transaction.IsActive)
        {
            session.Transaction.Commit();
            session.Transaction.Dispose();
            session.Dispose();
        }                    
    }
}
```

The problem is that the PerWebRequest lifestyle of Windsor has its own Application_EndRequest event handler which disposes of the service prior to my Application_EndRequest handler (in global.asax) executing, so the code in my Application_EndRequest handler never gets a chance to commit the transaction.  Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being committing my transaction in an event earlier in the ASP.NET lifecycle. I picked ReleaseRequestState, but any of the methods leading up to the EndRequest event should be adequate, as long as the handler has finished processing the request.

Answer (score 0):

I moved away from this pattern and rather have the commit happen in your controller action. Why wait until you have left the page and at the end of the request before committing. Makes passing UI messages a lot more difficult. Currently I take in the ISession as a param in the controller to ensure it gets injected:

```
public void SomeController(ISession session)
{
  _session = session;
}
```

then in your Action:

```
using(var trans = new _session.BeginTransaction()){
   try{
   ..update etc
   trans.commit();
   }
   catch(Exception ex){
   trans.rollback();
   // return message, log etc
   }
}
```

Windsor will cleanup the session for you at the end of the request.

Comment: This may work for simple isolated cases, but imagine a controller action that calls several services or accesses several repositories via their own separate (but identical, per web request) session reference. You can't have more than one active transaction per session.

Comment: Hi Chris. I use this for more than just "simple isolated cases" The same session is reused as Windosor will return the same session for the lifetime of the request. My comment was more about how long you want transactions open and where you want to commit. It also becomes more complicated showing error messages to clients when you are relying on transactions to be committed at the end of the request. I prefer to handle errors in the controller and display appropriate messages to the client.